# How to center time series of different lengths around specific points in a ggplot graphic

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, time-series, data-visualization

Consider `data` created here:

```r
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(time = c(1:1000, 1:1030, 1:2000), ID = rep(c('a','b','c'), c(1000,1030,2000)), variable = rnorm (4030))
```

We have measured some process `variable` over the life of 3 individuals, each of which is denoted with a unique `ID`. Assume that `time` is a function of each individuals size, so each `ID` has a different length. We have noticed some pattern or property within each time series that is consistent for each `ID`, meaning it happened in all of the time series (i.e., at some point in each `ID`'s life), but they are at different `time`s.
Lets say this happens at `time == 500` for individual `a`, at `time == 560` for individual `b`, and `time == 602` for individual `c`.

We can create a typical line plot to show each of the time series like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
data%>%
  ggplot(aes(time,variable, color = ID))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()
```

But how can we center each time series on these "common data points" to show how similar this "pattern" is in each `ID`? In other words, in the plot, `ID == c` will start first because it is the longest, and the data point 602 for `c` will be displayed at the same place as data point 500 for `ID == a` and data point 560 for `ID == b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you do:

```r
data$event_time <- rep(c(500, 560, 602), c(1000, 1030, 2000))

data %>%
  ggplot(aes(time - event_time, variable, color = ID)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = 2) +
  labs(x = "Time since life event")
```

[image]

Comment: this was clever thanks! Is there a way to do this without making the extra column in `data`? Say I have a large data set with many more `ID`s that I wanted to pull these three out of. In that case, it would be convenient to do this directly in the `dplyr` pipe or `ggplot` call

Comment: in other words, in the situation I just described, we would have to make `data2<-dplyr::filter(ID %in% c('a','b','c')` and then `data2$event_time <- rep(c(500, 560, 602), c(1000, 1030, 2000))` in order to do your process, so i was curious how it could be done without making new objects